# ftp file download result in black screen

Tags: android, ftp, download, screen

I am downloading a file from ftp server. downloading code worked fine, however after download code screen doesn't show anything ,it gets black. Also download function is not returning true value, even the file is being saved in the specified directory.

```
  public class FTPClass{
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_file_player);

                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    dirname = intent.getStringExtra("currentDirName");


    MyFTPClient mftp = new MyFTPClient();
    createPath = mftp.getAppRootPath().concat("/"+ dirname);
    mftp.setCurrentDir(createPath);
    System.out.println(mftp.ftpChangeDirectory(createPath));

    FTPFile[] farr = mftp.ftpListAllFiles();
    System.out.println(farr.length);

    for(int i = 0; i<farr.length;i++){
        System.out.println("SRC: "+createPath+"/"+farr[i].getName());

        String src = createPath+"/"+farr[i].getName();
        System.out.println("DEST: "+"/data/data/com.example.ftpplayer" + "/app_"+dirname);
        String dest ="/data/data/com.example.ftpplayer" + "/app_"+dirname+"/"+farr[i].getName();
        System.out.println(mftp.downloadFile(src,dest));
    }
}
}

public class CallingIntent extends Activity{
        System.out.println("In item click ");
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FTPClass.class);
            String dir = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
            intent.putExtra("currentDirName", dir);
            startActivity(intent);

}
 public class MyFTPClient{

 public boolean downloadFile(String srcPath , String destPath){

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destPath);
        System.out.println(mftp.retrieveFile(srcPath, fos)); // retrieve file doesn't return true
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        return true;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}

}
```

Comment: FTPClass should probably be have `extends Activity` , and CallingIntent should probably have an `onCreate` method. I didn't try it, but I don't think this should run as is.

Comment: Ya I m sry . FTPClass and CallingIntent is an activity.I escaped that code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your code on the background thread, try using an asyncTask.

Comment: Is Strictmode policy is the reason for not getting true from retrieveFile method. Also the log doesn't show any error.